# Avoid rounding to 0 when a result is very little

Tags: t-sql, floating-point, decimal, rounding

I've searched for this but i didn't find anything, i hope this is not a doubled question.
I'm doing a formula in TSQL like this:

```
@Temp = SQRT((((@Base1 - 1) * (@StDev1 * @StDev1)) 
        + ((@AvgBase - 1) * (@AvgStDev * @AvgStDev))) 
        * ((1 / @Base1) + (1 / @AvgBase)) 
        / (@Base1 + @AvgBase - 2))
```

But it always returns me a 0.
`@Base1` and `@AvgBase` are `int`, the rest of parameters are `float`, but i've also tried with `decimal(15,15)`.
I tried also changing the self multiplication with the function `POWER()` but the only problem i can't solve is this part: `(1 / @Base1) + (1 / @AvgBase)`, because `@Base1` and `@AvgBase` are so big, and the result of the calc is 0,0001... and some more numbers. How can i force the engine to not round the result to 0? Thanks

EDIT: I solved it changing the `@AvgBase` and the `@Base1` to `float` type. I guess that the result `1/@param`, with `@param` -> `int` gives you the rounded result and when you go for casting it or whatever, you are working on a rounded result anyway.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to create a `@INVBase1 = (1/@Base1)` ? will this also be rounded to 0? what happens when you play around with the data format of this new variable?

alternatively have you tried

```
/ ((@Base1) + (@AvgBase))
```

instead of

```
* ((1 / @Base1) + (1 / @AvgBase))
```

Comment: i tried the support parameter (actually i'm working with those but to explain the problem i had to share the entire formula), and it's the same. The second option is not correct because a/(b+c) is diffrent than a*((1/b)+(1/c))

Comment: I see. you would need to try a/b + a/c then.

Comment: I think the problem is that base1 and avg base are integers. 1 will be casted as int as well. so you will have an integer calculation returning an integer. but you want a numeric value. what about * CAST(((1 / @Base1) + (1 / @AvgBase)) AS NUMERIC(20,18)) ?